# NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest - is it possible to implement without leak

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

Is there a way to implement NSURLConnection without it leaking? A number of Apps including NYTimes and others (including mine) suffer from this. Anyone have a working implementation?

Comment: Could you provide any substantial evidence that this class has a leak? I'd be interested to see it.
Also, what version of iPhone OS is this seen in?
Have you reported the leak to Apple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that best practice is to use NSURLConnection asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:), `+[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]` is built on top of the asynchronous loading code made available by `NSURLConnection`. It would not be difficult to reimplement this by spawning and blocking on an `NSThread`, running the request asynchronously in the background on a run loop and ending the thread once either `connectionDidFinishLoading:` or `connection:didFailWithError:` is received.

<sub>Of course, you are better off using the asynchronous code in the first place; it makes for a much better user experience</sub>

Comment: calling sendSynchronousRequest asynchronously is a lot simpler than implementing the asynchronous request yourself.