# Leaking sendSynchronousRequest using blocks, ARC

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, memory-leaks, block

The instruments show leak in my code:
Leak: CFHTTPCookieStorage 
-> `NSData *resultData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]; //100.0%`

I perform asynchronous downloading using blocks:

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:user.user_photo];
   NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [NSURLConnection asyncRequestSimple:request success:^(NSData *data) {
        user.user_photo_data=data;
        NSLog(@"Image Downloaded");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        });     

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failed downloading");
    }];
```

My asynchronous implementation using categories:

**NSURLConnection+MyExtensions.h**

```
+ (void)asyncRequestSimple:(NSURLRequest *)request success:(void(^)(NSData* data))successBlock_ failure:(void(^)(NSError *error))failureBlock_;
```

**NSURLConnection+MyExtensions.m**

```
+ (void)asyncRequestSimple:(NSURLRequest *)request success:(void(^)(NSData* data))successBlock_ failure:(void(^)(NSError *error))failureBlock_
{

     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *resultData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];//100% leak

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        });

        if (error) {
            failureBlock_(error);
        } else {
            successBlock_(resultData);
        }
    });
}
```

Why does it leak?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is already an argument `NSData *data`

Comment: I changed the name, the leak stays the same

Comment: I don't see a leak here. Are you sure you aren't leaking that `resultData` somewhere else? Perhaps in your success block?

Comment: In the instruments there is the following line highlighted in red color with 100% leak title:  NSData *resultData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

Comment: Are you profiling on the device or simulator?

Comment: on the simulator, I added the images

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330135/nsurlconnection-sendsynchronousrequest-is-it-possible-to-implement-without-lea

Comment: I'm sorry but it has not helped me

Comment: See this question, might give you a clue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116205/getting-leak-in-leak-in-nsurlconnection-sendsynchronousrequesttherequest-retur